# Twitter REST API vs Streaming API - how does it impacts server side

Tags: http, web-applications, twitter, websocket

There is an application that should read user tweets for every registered user, process them and store data for future usage.
It can reach Twitter 2 ways: either REST API (poll twitter every x mins), or use its Streaming API to get tweets delivered.

Besides completely different implementations on server side I wonder what are other impacts on server side?

Say application has tousands of users. Is it better to build kind of queue and poll twitter for each user (the simplest scenario), or is it better to use Streaming API and keep HTTP connection open for each user? I'm a bit worried about the latter as it'd require keeping tousands of connections open all the time. Are there any drawbacks of that I'm not aware of? If I'd like to deploy my app on Heroku or on EC2 instance, would it be ok or are there any limits?

How it is done in other apps that constantly need getting data for each user?